# Toolbar position changes with paging

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-maps-v2

I have been dealing with an issue regarding the CollapsingToolbarLayout, Toolbar when dealing with a ViewPager.

The issue is that the position of the Toolbar in the second page (always the 2nd page only) is incorrect. Then in the third, fourth ... pages it is correct again. Pretty hard to explain thoroughly so I include images. The first image shows the first page which is how it should look like. The second image shows both of the pages when swiping to the second one - notice the home button.
[image: The first page - which is correct]

[image: The second page and the first one together, notice the back button]

I have tried replacing the map with an ImageView and I get the same results.

The Activity / Fragment Structure is in this way:
ItemActivity -> ItemPagerFragment -> ItemDetailsFragment

The Toolbar is set in the Fragment and not the activity and the layout structure is the following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/cl_root"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="355dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:mapType="satellite"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<include layout="@layout/merge_loading"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_small"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_search_blank"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

With the help of Nguyễn Trung Hiếu answer I managed to figure this out. The only thing needed was to remove - android:fitsSystemWindows="true" - from the Coordinator Layout.

Comment: Had similar problem yesterday ... which design support library are you using?  I solved it by updating  com.android.support:design: 22.2.0  to 22.2.1

Comment: Are you really need `CollapsingToolbarLayout` there?

Comment: @incr3diblenoob was using 23.2.1 and just updated to 23.3.0 and the issue still exists.

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Well I don't really need it but its functionality fits the bill perfectly for me in this case. That is having the automatic parallaxing, moving the title to the toolbar etc.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

at

```
android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
```

This is code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/cl_root"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="355dp"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:mapType="satellite"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
 android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:visibility="visible"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

 <include layout="@layout/merge_loading"/>

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
 android:id="@+id/fab"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_small"
 android:src="@drawable/icon_search_blank"
 app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
 app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The same thing happens, but now the first one is displayed with a margin of the size of the status bar, so it is kind of worse.

Comment: Try change android:fitsSystemWindows="true" at Control different.

Comment: Your comment got me to the right solution - It was just the opposite. It worked like a charm after removing the fitsSystemWindow from CoordinatorLayout but keeping it on all the other elements.